# Possible to have Mercurial log incoming changesets?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I've been trying to hook into Mercurial in order to log groups of changesets that are pulled into the local working repository.  In other words, I want to be able to view a history of changes that were pulled into the *local repository*.  As it stands right now, I'm using the "prechangegroup" hook to, in turn, call `hg incoming` which then writes to a logfile which can later be parsed.

I'm curious if I'm reinventing the wheel here though.  Are there any extensions out there that allow to me to query for this information directly through Mercurial instead of having to write to a separate log file?  It would be nice to be able to use some kind of `hg pullhistory --template...` command to be able to get this information and format it instead of hoping that the user configures their system correctly so that the log directory is writable, etc.

Comment: Performance testing.  When monitoring the performance of a project, it's necessary to know what and when stuff changed in the LOCAL environment.  We have performance metrics scripts that monitor site performance but it's difficult to track down why something is not working correctly or is working poorly if you don't know when things were introduced into the live application code-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla uses something like this.  They call it the "pushlog": http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/pushloghtml

They have a hook that pushes records into a database (IIRC) from a changegroup hook.  The source for their's is available, so you're re-inventing the wheel, but it's such a small, specialized wheel, that's probably okay.

Comment: Bingo.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you very much Ry4an!